# nginx map routes by docker host, for each route, call a different container

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, routes, nodes

I'm trying to map routes by docker host, for each route, call a different container.

I have a docker-compose with 2 services, and that services is in :5000 port. My nginx.conf is mapped following below code:

```
location /template-api {

        rewrite ^/template-api/?(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass         http://template-api:5000;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }

    location /api-plan  {
            rewrite ^/api-plan/?(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_pass         http://api-plan:5000;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }
```

When, I call localhost:8000/api-template/documentation,  the route that calls a static file, or route that returns a static file. He is returning error in localhost:8000/swaggerui, with file is not found. 
That erros happens because the swagger ui folder is in localhost:8000/api-template/swaggerui and localhost:8000/api-plan/swaggerui

To fix that error, I'm add to ngix, the conf to map `/` route:

```
server { 
listen 8000;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/api.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/api_error.log;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://api-plan:5000;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

    }
```

Now when I call localhost:8000/api-plan/documentation, results in success, but, when I call localhost:8000/template-api/documentation, the API redirects to localhost:8000/api-plan/ resulting in wrong route.

Comment: can't you just create two different locations instead of root route / ?

Comment: If, I remove that location, when the browser calls localhost:5000/swagger, He don't understand where must look for static files :/

Comment: event if you keep 3 different locations? A root location to static files and 2 more locations to these swaggerui endpoints. I think this would work

Comment: Yes! I think in that possibility, Im searching how I do this thing hahaha

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
server { 
    listen 8000;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/api.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/api_error.log;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://$server_name:8080/swaggerUi;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

    }
    location /template-api {

            rewrite ^/template-api/?(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_pass         http://template-api:5000;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }

    location /api-plan  {
            rewrite ^/api-plan/?(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_pass         http://api-plan:5000;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, this is exactly the same approach I would take!

Comment: the $servername returns the name of server, defined in line 3

Answer (score 1):

You can use cookies to detect which backend should receive the `/swaggerui` request. This is highly insecure since users can edit the cookie and try to reach other hosts but since it's a local test environment it just works.

```
server { 
    listen 8000;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/api.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/api_error.log;
    server_name localhost;

    location ~ ^/swaggerui {
            resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;
            proxy_pass         http://$cookie_origin:5000;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

    }

    location /template-api {
            rewrite ^/template-api/?(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_pass         http://template-api:5000;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            add_header         Set-Cookie "origin=template-api;Domain=localhost;Path=/;Max-Age=100000";
    }

    location /api-plan  {
            rewrite ^/api-plan/?(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_pass         http://api-plan:5000;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            add_header         Set-Cookie "origin=plan-api;Domain=localhost;Path=/;Max-Age=100000";
    }
}
```

Comment: Works to me! But, now, when swagger requests, he is calling to `http://api-plan/v1/` when the correct is `http://localhost:8000/api-plan/v1/`